# Connection time needed from USA to Heathrow to Shannon

Tags: lhr, short-connections

On April 18, 2017, we are flying from Salt Lake City, Utah, USA on Delta Airlines flight DL 50 arriving Heathrow Airport at 1:20pm April 19, 2017,  on one ticket. Then on a separate ticket, we fly Aer Lingus to Shannon Airport on flight EI 385, departing Heathrow at 2:45PM. Will we have enough time to get through customs, baggage claim and check in for the Ireland flight? How much time will be necessary to make this connection?

Comment: At LHR, which terminals do you arrive at and depart from?

Comment: According to http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/which-terminal., looks like arriving Terminal 3 and departing Terminal 2.  The only service to Shannon is shown as Aer Lingus, so the "BA" flight is probably a codeshare (that's consistent with the flight number).

Comment: Arrive lhr terminal 3, depart terminal 2

Comment: What time does the second flight leave?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan 2:45PM

Comment: I would not try 1:25 on a single ticket transfer! If I have my data correct, the official MCT for a connection like this is 1:15. And it's the UK so you need to clear some truly obnoxious security. Two tickets is absolutely hopeless.

Answer (score 12):

You're arriving at Heathrow at 1:20PM and are connecting on a separate ticket to a flight departing at 2:45PM?

Forget it, just ***forget it***, and rebook your connection ***immediately***. There's one at 7:35PM, which you would make. But the 2:45PM one on a separate ticket? You're not ***nearly*** getting through immigration, baggage claim, from T3 to T2 and through security in that time, ***period***.

Comment: Customs at Heathrow usually takes zero time if you have nothing to declare - just walk through the green exit from baggage claim. That said, I agree with the answer. Any delay in the transatlantic flight and the OP may not even have their baggage when the gate for the second flight is closing.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Now that's optimistic. If they're US citizens, chances are they wouldn't even be through immigration if there are several long-haul arrivals.

Comment: @Crazydre I'm a British Citizen, and was thinking in terms of how long it takes me from aircraft to baggage claim at Heathrow. It will be longer for any non-EU citizen.